# How to sort object list of class which is an imported dependency in your project

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

The class imported as dependency in my project doesnt override compareTo method. Is there a way i can create this sorting logic on my own without request a change on the dependent project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can always implement a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) yourself:

```
public class SomeClassComparator implements Comparator<SomeClass> {
    @Override
    int compare (SomeClass o1, SomeClass o2) {
        // Just an example
        return Integer.compare(o1.getSomeInt(), o2.getSomeInt());
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect!! Exactly i was looking for. Thanks @Mureinik

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<YourObject>() {

    public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
        return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
    }
});
```